# Тире или дефис?

Tags: дефис

Запуталась - здесь нужно тире или дефис? Если бы было "предприятий-производителей" без оборудования, то ясно, что дефис. А в этом случае?

Для реального подъема предприятий — производителей оборудования, активизации разработки и внедрения инноваций необходима их поддержка и прежде всего со стороны заинтересованных отраслей и структур, т.к. реализация государственных и региональных программ потребует длительного времени.

В докладе будут представлены результаты работы с проектными институтами, заказчиками и заводами — производителями арматуры по повышению эффективности управления трубопроводной арматурой, повышению точности управления технологическим процессом, результаты работы по решению вопросов импортозамещения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенных примерах требуется тире. Т.е. тире характеризует тип предприятия, его деятельность. Дефис обозначал бы просто название предприятия. Как вы правильно отметили, "Если бы было "предприятий-производителей" без оборудования, то ясно, что дефис".

Answer (score 1):

А запятая нужна? Присоединительный член предложение, вводное слово И ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО в роли присоединительного союза.

Для реального подъема предприятий — производителей оборудования, активизации разработки и внедрения инноваций необходима их поддержка, и прежде всего со стороны заинтересованных отраслей и структур, т.к. реализация государственных и региональных программ потребует длительного времени.

Comment: Да, запятая здесь на месте. Смотрится.

Comment: Запятая действительно нужна. Только вряд ли "прежде всего" можно назвать здесь вводным словом. Прежде всего - "во-первых" "главное"? Здесь Прежде все - "сперва" "вначале" "в первую очередь". Т.е. наречное выражение.

Comment: Важно то, что здесь это выражение выступает в роли присоединительного союза. Фактически мы имеем наречное выражение, которое может выполнять различные функции - быть обстоятельством, вводным словом, присоединительным союзом.